# Getting 404 error in response in case POST request in Jmeter

Tags: jmeter

I have captured a scenario by different request:

1. Login
2. Add some details.
3. Upload a document.
4. Getting a detail page.

Everything is fine until landing to the *Add Detail* page. I'm getting perfect response but in case of adding details in a post request, I'm getting `error 404` with blank response.

I have added a response assertion to match the a piece of text for which page user navigate after add details.

In add detail page there is also a dynamic URL which had correlate.

[image]

Help please!

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DNf7e.png)

Comment: Basically I am getting previous request response in my next POST request  ,If some one have any idea...help please!

Comment: Still waiting ....I think.,there is no solution of this issue...

Comment: Please refer screen of request of my post request element

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what is causing that problem but i noticed you have "Use multipartform-data for HTTP POST" checked which is used for uploading files why don't you remove that check from there and try.

Comment: I tried by uncheck "Use multipartform-data for HTTP POST" but it is still not working

Answer (score 0):

From "Recording Controller" I can see:

```
/home/-/mylead/add
```

And from your request:

```
/my-leads/add
```

As HTTP 404 response code stands for ["Not Found"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_404) my expectation is that this is the problem.

Also double check your correlated values, in case if they fall back to defaults you'll can get flaky behaviour. See [How to debug your Apache JMeter script](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-debug-your-apache-jmeter-script) article for some hints.

Comment: Now I am not getting 404 error but it is still not passed by response assertion ,I am getting previous request 's response when I check response in HTML in view result tress Listener , I have also check dynamic variable in debug sampler it is fine there..still not getting where I am wrong.....Help Please!

Answer (score 0):

Could you try to change implementation to java and uncheck encode for the first parameter? And should  try to work with body data instead of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue by changing the match no. in regex extractor.
There were 2 dynamic variables p_p_auth and p_auth the regex extractor

```
p_auth=(.+?)&
```

matches for p_p_auth in first 5 match then match for p_auth so I changed match no to 6 this resolve my problem

Thanks to all for support.